# Inequalities involving liminf and limsup

Tags: inequality

I got homework about liminf and limsup.

--Edit--

I guess that it would be better writing the question and my solution here...

**Question:**
Let $ a_n,b_n $ be sequences.

Given that $ a=\underline{lim} (a_n) \ , \ b=\underline{lim}(b_n) \ , \ A=\overline{lim}(a_n) \ , \ B=\overline{lim}(b_n) $, prove that:

$ a+b \leq \underline{lim}(a_n+b_n) \leq a+B \leq \overline{lim}(a_n+b_n) \leq A+B $

**Solution:**

(1) $ a+b \leq \underline{lim}(a_n+b_n) $

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \ a \leq a_n $ and $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \ b \leq b_n $. We can sum these inequalities, thus $ a+b \leq a_n+b_n $ and this is sufficient for $ a+b \leq \underline{lim}(a_n+b_n) $.

(2) $\underline{lim}(a_n+b_n) \leq a+B $

We can write $ \underline{lim}(a_n)=\underline{lim}([a_n+b_n]-b_n) $.
according to (1) $\underline{lim}([a_n+b_n]-b_n) \geq \underline{lim}(a_n+b_n)+\underline{lim}(-b_n) $, but $ \underline{lim}(-x_n)=-\overline{lim}(x_n) $,
thus $\underline{lim}(a_n) \geq \underline{lim}(a_n+b_n)-\overline{lim}(b_n) $.
Eventually, $\underline{lim}(a_n+b_n) \leq a+B $.

(3) $\overline{lim}(a_n+b_n) \leq A+B$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \ a_n \leq A$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \ b_n \leq B$
We can sum these inequalities, thus $a_n+b_n \leq A+B$ and this is sufficient for $\overline{lim}(a_n+b_n) \leq A+B$.

(4) $a+B \leq \overline{lim}(a_n+b_n)$

We can write $\overline{lim}(b_n)=\overline{lim}([a_n+b_n]-a_n)$. according to (3) $\overline{lim}([a_n+b_n]-a_n) \leq \overline{lim}(a_n+b_n)+\overline{lim}(-a_n)$, but $ \overline{lim}(-x_n)=-\underline{lim}(x_n)$, thus $\overline{lim}(b_n) \leq \overline{lim}(a_n+b_n)-\underline{lim}(a_n)$.
Eventually,$a+B  \leq \overline{lim}(a_n+b_n)$.

Can someone check my solution and give feedback?

Thank you!

Comment: I published a link to my work. I would be happy if someone will check it.